# Positioning problems of slider navigation in tablet widths

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm finishing up work on [this website](http://parpeds.com/test-homepage/) and trying to finalize the positioning of the slider navigation; however, I'm struggling to get the position correct on approximately tablet width screens (550px-768px).

I think something is off with my media queries and sizing but I can't put my finger on why I can't lock the position down between that range!

Here's [a link to the correct behavior](http://parpeds.com/). Any ideas?

Slider uses Cycle2, if it matters!

Sample HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-pager="#adv-custom-pager" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="7000">

<div class="singleSlide">
<!-- content goes in here -->
</div>

<div id="sliderNav">

<div id="adv-custom-pager">
    <span class=""></span>
    <span class=""></span>
    <span class=""></span>
</div>

</div>
```

And CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 550px) {
     #sliderNav {
     bottom:145px;
     }

     .slidercaption {
     height:250px;
     }
}
```

Comment: we didnt get it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the slider at that point.

To be honest when I add a slider to a  website, I usually turn it off for mobiles and have just 1 image visible (to break the text up). The viewpoint is so small, people won't wait to watch for the slider to change unlike desktops when they could be reading something else and notice it change.